# Oracle MERGE statements executed in parallel transactions: How to prevent duplicate keys?

Tags: sql, oracle

Let us imagine we have some nice, simple table:

```
CREATE TABLE blah (
    some_key VARCHAR(32),
    some_value VARCHAR(32)
);
```

For some reason we do not want to define a primary key or a unique index on the `some_key` column.

We now execute to `MERGE` statements in parallel transactions (i.e. the second one is started before the first one committed):

```
MERGE INTO blah blah
USING (SELECT 'some_key' some_key, 'a_value' some_value FROM DUAL) rec
ON (blah.some_key = rec.some_key)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET blah.some_value = rec.some_value
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT (blah.some_key, blah.some_value) VALUES (rec.some_key, rec.some_value);
```

and:

```
...
USING (SELECT 'some_key' some_key, 'another_value' some_value FROM DUAL) rec
...
```

After committing both a `SELECT`shows the following:

```
| SOME_KEY | SOME_VALUE    | 
|----------|---------------|
| some_key | a_value       |
| some_key | another_value |
```

I understand the mechanics behind this (i.e. the two merge statements not "seeing" each other), but this is somehow clearly not the desired result.

Of course I can define a `UNIQUE` key. Then the second staements fails - which is also explainable but somehow unexpected from the `MERGE`statement.

Is there any way to make `MERGE` do a "real" `MERGE` without any duplicate "keys"?

Comment: No. in a parallel scenario, you can't prevent duplicates 100% without some for of a unique constraint. Unless you don't mind placing a lock on the whole table for the duration of your transaction that is (unlikely).

Comment: No, a lock on the whole table isn't really what I'm looking for ;-)

Comment: I didn't think so :). But I did post an answer that may be helpful to you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it makes sense to create a unique constraint on `some_key`, then you really should create it.  It's the only way to completely prevent duplicate keys.

Besides creating the unique constraint, it sounds like, what you're really after, is to be able to *serialize* the merge statements. In other words, to guarantee that 2 concurrent users can never truly run both `merge` statements at the same time. Rather, one must wait after the other to complete, without the hassle of one of the users getting an error.

Here is an idea to achieve that that doesn't involve locking the whole table you're merging into. You can create a separate table designed specifically to serialize entire operations. You then place a lock on a specific row of that table that represents your operation by using a `select ... for update`. This, in effect, serializes access to the `merge` statement.  And then, after you perform the `merge`, you commit the transaction to allow others to perform the `merge` as well, but only after the changes become visible to the other transactions.

Here is a sample script to give you an idea:

**Setup**

```
create table operation_lock (
  operation_name varchar2(50) not null
)
/

alter table operation_lock
add constraint operation_lock_pk
primary key (operation_name)
/

insert into operation_lock (operation_name) values ('my_merge_operation')
/

commit
/
```

**How you would run the `merge` operation in a transaction**

```
select * from operation_lock
 where operation_name = 'my_merge_operation'
   for update
/

merge into blah blah...
/

commit
/
```

Comment: Yes, serialization is the keyword. Nice to hear that there are possibilities to solve this.